# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Attempt to modify property "results" on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\TestLink\cfg\const.inc.php:409

Tags: xampp, testlink

I am trying to install TestLink following [this tutorialspoint guide](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/testlink/testlink_installation.htm#). However, when I navigate to `http://localhost/Testlink` in my browser to access the installation page, I get the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Attempt to modify property "results" on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\TestLink\cfg\const.inc.php:409 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\TestLink\install\index.php(20): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\TestLink\cfg\const.inc.php on line 409
```

My config files everywhere are untouched except config.inc.php to edit path `$tlCfg->log_path` and `$g_repositoryPath`.

How do I install TestLink?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit this in const.inc.php

```
$tlCfg = new stdClass();
$tlCfg->results['status_code'] = array (
    'failed' => 'f',
    'blocked' => 'b',
    'passed' => 'p',
    'not_run'       => 'n',
    'not_available' => 'x',
    'unknown'       => 'u',
    'all'           => 'a'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

$tlCfg = new stdClass();

at line 409 of const.inc.php

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).